# Where does the "l" command come from on my system?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ls

My Ubuntu allows the use of `l` as a command to print out the current directory much like `ls` except that it is actually better in that it specifies which are folders, files, and executables.

Is this an existing command or did I configure my system (like `la` for `ls -a` and `ll` for `ls -l`) and forget about it? (it's not in my `.bashrc`)

Comment: I can't connect to my linux machine right now, but I think type or which will tell you if it's an alias, and what it's an alias for.

Answer (score 4):

My `.bashrc` has the following alias, included by default in Debian-based distributions (and probably others):

```
alias l='ls -CF'
```

Comment: oh shoot you're right, it was in my .bashrc and I missed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Typically these are shortcuts that are implemented as aliases.  Type `alias` at your prompt and you'll see a list of all of your aliases.  If you don't have it explicitly defined in your .bashrc, it maybe in a system-wide bashrc in `/etc/`

Comment: i actually couldn't find a `.bashrc` in `/etc/` - it was actually in `/root/`

Comment: It most likely won't be called `.bashrc` in etc, but the name is system dependent.  For example on my machine I have `/etc/bash.bashrc` for my system-wide settings.

Comment: oh yeah, bash.bashrc on mine (ubuntu 10.10) too - good call